# What determines which combo starters you have?

Tags: sanctuary-rpg

As the barbarian, sometimes I'm presented with Cleave, Whirlwind, and Frenzy as my starters, and sometimes I have Brutal Rend, Rupture, and Ground Stomp. Generally, I like the latter set better, but I don't know how to get it to reliably appear.

What determines which moves I can use to start a combo?